# Calculating theoretical network bandwidth in topology

Tags: networking, simulation, topology, traffic-simulation

I'm in the process of building a discrete-event simulator, and need to be able to calculate the theoretical bandwidth available between two systems in a given network topology, so that I can "time" how long a transfer will take to occur and create an event at its expected completion time.

At the moment, for simplicity, I do not consider the switch's backplanes or likelyhood for collisions / congestion to occur within the network. I am simply interested in the maximum transfer rate between all systems communicating.

For instance, consider the following sample network topology:
[image: sample topology]

We assume the following connections:

```
Source 1, Source 2 -> (sending to) Dest 1
Source 3, Source 4 -> (sending to) Dest 2
```

Given these connections, what is the maximum effective transfer rate of all sources?

If we visualize this as a graph, I can calculate this manually by starting from the sources and evaluating at each switch level the maximum amount of incoming network traffic vs the switch's uplink.

For instance, Source #1 in this scenario has 50 Mbps of effective bandwidth to Dest 1

```
1 Gbps * S1(1/2) * S2(1) * S3(1/10) = 50 Mbps
```

However, I'm curious as to what other methods can be utilized to calculate this, or if there is a more effective approach which I can utilize to "predict" network traffic.

Any feedback is appreciated -- thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a max-min fairness problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-min_fairness

The progressive filling algorithm (described in the Wiki article) is a simple solution to this problem:

> If resources are allocated in advance in the network nodes, max-min
>   fairness can be obtained by using an algorithm of progressive filling.
>   You start with all rates equal to 0 and grow all rates together at the
>   same pace, until one or several link capacity limits are hit. The
>   rates for the sources that use these links are not increased any more,
>   and you continue increasing the rates for other sources. All the
>   sources that are stopped have a bottleneck link. This is because they
>   use a saturated link, and all other sources using the saturated link
>   are stopped at the same time, or were stopped before, thus have a
>   smaller or equal rate. The algorithm continues until it is not
>   possible to increase. Lastly, when the algorithm terminates, all
>   sources have been stopped at some time and thus have a bottleneck
>   link. This allocation is max-min fair.